# Kivy boxlayout inside gridlayout

Tags: python, kivy

I'm new to programming, and I'm  writing a small app in Kivy. I have been stuck for a few days. what I initially wanted was several buttons in a GridLayout with the buttons text dynamically added in Python. I wanted the text on the button to be organized in sections.

For example, on the extreme left of the button should be the room number, the center should be the name of the user, the extreme right should be the time, and at the bottom of the button I want a max of 40 characters message that the user can add. since the information is dynamically added, I found it difficult to do it on a single button without interfering with the position of the other information added on the button. Moreover, on_press on any of the button I want to be able to change the background_color of the button.

So, my solution was to separate the different section of the button by creating first a BoxLayout with a canvas, then add 4 buttons with each button text being respectively (room #, name, time and user message) on different buttons. I will set the alpha value of the button color to 0 to make the 4 buttons looks like a single button and add it to the GridLayout. I also need to be able to update the color of the canvas dynamically, but not sure if it is possible

I have been able to do some of this in .kv file but not in Python, so here are my questions:

1. Is there there an easier way to do this?
2. how can this be done in Python?
3. since I need to change the canvas color of the BoxLayout when the button is press, how do K keep track of all the BoxLayout and change their color.

Here is an example of the .kv file I wrote

```
ScreenManagement:
    Screen:
        ScrollView:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            GridLayout:
                spacing:10
                id:grid
                row_default_height:230

                cols:1
                size_hint_y:None

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgb:0,1,0
                        Rectangle:
                            pos:self.pos
                            size:self.size
                    Button:
                        background_color:0,1,0

                    Button:
                        text:

                        background_color:1,1,0
                        text_size: self.size
                        #halign: 'left'

                BoxLayout: #this box has 4 btn that looks like 1btn  
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgb:0,1,0
                        Rectangle:
                            pos:self.pos
                            size:self.size
                    Button:
                        background_color:(0,1,0,.1)
                    Button:
                        background_color:(0,1,0,.1)

                    Button:
                        background_color:(0,1,0,.1)

                    Label:
                        background_color:(0,1,0,1)

                BoxLayout:
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgb:1,1,1,1
                        Rectangle:
                            pos:self.pos
                            size:self.size
                    Button:  
                        background_color:(0,1,0,1)

                    Button:
                        background_color:(1,0,0,1)
```

Here is the Python code which is not doing what I want

```
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def box(self):
        layout=self.ids.grid #gridlayout in .kv file
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height')) 
        for i in range(10):
            btn1=Button(background_color=(0,1,0,1), text=str(i))           
            lbl=Button(background_color=(0,1,0,1),text='label')         
            btn=Button(background_color=(0,1,0,1),text='label')         


            b=BoxLayout(height=10,text='chien',background_color=(1,0,01),orientation='vertical',size_hint_y=None)         
            with b.canvas.before:
                b.color=Color(btn1.background_color)
                b.rect=Rectangle(pos=bpos, size=self.ids.grid.size,orientation='horizontal')
            b.add_widget(btn1)
            b.add_widget(lbl)
            b.add_widget(btn)
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(b) #grid is a gridlayout in .kv file

Class testApp(App):
    def build(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testApp().run()
```